# What the difference between “bristly” and “briery”

Tags: meaning, difference

I don't understand the difference between these words.

Whats does mean each word?
In whats cases, can I use each word?

I saw these words in Google Translate, Collins, Lexico.

Google Translate - both words mean *barbed* (adv).

Lexico - *bristly* means *barbed* (adv) - as I'm understood.
*briery* - not find this word.

Collins - same as Lexico.

I'm not sure that Google Translate correctly translated *briery* 'cause Google Translate offered me one result only. Also, Collins and Lexico have not this word. It looks like English has no word. But Google Translate translated it.

Comment: Hi, I was one of three users who voted to close the same question which you deleted on EL&U. You should tell us what word or expression you were trying to translate in English and why you think [*briery* is a word](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/briery) you need to learn, it is very rarely used in the English language. I found another source [here](https://www.yourdictionary.com/briery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on anything that Google translate says, especially for obscure words.

If you consult a good dictionary like the Cambridge dictionary, it says that [bristly](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bristly) is "with short stiff hairs" it's a term you would use about a man who hasn't shaved for a couple of days, or about a toothbrush.

Briary isn't in the dictionary, but something that is briary is like a [briar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/briar), which is "a wild bush, especially a rose bush with long stems and sharp thorns". You would use briary about a plant that has sharp thorns.

Comment: I say about *briery*, not *briary*. Or do you want to say that *briery* and *briary* mean the same?

Comment: _Brier_ is a spelling variant of _briar_.

Comment: https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/briery Quotations: *We hear them most often in bushy fields and open second-growths, along hedge-rows or from **briery clumps** in which the bird's nest may be hidden*

Comment: I want to thank all. Now I more understand about these words.